# Regular expression for string of digits with no repeated digits?

Tags: regex

I'm reading through the [dragon book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811) and trying to solve an exercise that is stated as follows

> Write regular definitions for the following languages:
>
> - All strings of digits with no repeated digits. *Hint:* Try this problem first with a few digits, such as { 0, 1, 2 }.

Despite having tried to solve it for hours, I can't imagine a solution, beside the extremely wordy

```
d0 -> 0?
d1 -> 1?
d2 -> 2?
d3 -> 3?
d4 -> 4?
d5 -> 5?
d6 -> 6?
d7 -> 7?
d8 -> 8?
d9 -> 9?
d10 -> d0d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d8d9 | d0d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d9d8 | ...
```

Hence having to write `10!` alternatives in `d10`. Since we shall *write* this regular definition, I doubt that this is a proper solution. Can you help me please?

Comment: A disccussion of a similar question is at: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=353072

Comment: Perhaps using call backs would help?

Comment: Maybe the author is trying to show you that a regular expression isn't always the most compact representation?  A finite state machine to do this would be pretty compact.  It is fairly easy to show this is a regular language but that doesn't mean it has a short representation as a regular expression...  As others noted if the complement operator is allowed things change.  Wikipedia has a good discussion under Regular Expression.

Comment: Actually maybe there's no compact FSM either.  The problem is there is a lot of state to capture all combinations of digits seen so far.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether "no repeated digits" means "no instances of two consecutive digits which are the same" or "no digit may appear twice anywhere in the string". Does the book provide any clues to disambiguate?

Comment: @Peter it provides no clues :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the question didn't necessarily ask you to write a regular *expression*, it asked you to provide a regular *definition*, which I interpret to include NFA's. It turns out it doesn't matter which you use, as all NFA's can be shown to be mathematically equivalent to regular expressions.

Using the digits 0, 1, and 2, a valid NFA would be the following (sorry for the crummy diagram):

[image]

Each state represents the last digit scanned in the input, and there are no loops on any of the nodes, therefore this is an accurate representation of a string with no repeated digits from the set {0,1,2}. Extending this is trivial (although it requires a large whiteboard :) ).

NOTE: I am making the assumption that the string "0102" IS valid, but the string "0012" is not.

This can be converted to a regular expression (although it will be painful) by using the algorithm described [here](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/Users/faculty/young/OldFiles/CS-Classes/csse474/201440/Resources/ConvertDFSMtoRegExp.pdf).

Comment: It's not hard to translate to a modern regex, especially if you're targeting an engine that supports backreferences in negative lookahead assertions (i.e., a recursive engine, such as PCRE). An RE like `^(?:(?!([0-2])\1).)*$` would seem appropriate (or failing that, expanding the possibilities for negative lookahead patterns). Without negative lookaheads, the regexp will be very painful, especially with larger alphabets…

Comment: @DonalFellows, we cannot use a negative lookahead (just look at the downvoted answer). Most lexical analyzers deal with regular expressions in a very theoretical sense.

Comment: I am probably doing something wrong, but when I used the procedure described in the PDF, the resulting regular expression does not appear to match the strings `01`, `02`, `012`, `020`, `021`, `0101`, and others. It appears to match any infinite string of {0, 1, 2} having non-consecutive-repeating digits, but not all finite-length strings meeting the same criterion.

Comment: That's why I did it as a comment on a _correct_ (and attractive) answer (I like the diagram; makes it clear). I just felt that it is useful to provide a perspective on how this would be written as a regexp (distinguishing that from classical “regular expressions” though).

Comment: @DanielTrebbien, like I said, it's painful. I did it on paper and the result is not worth adding to the answer. If you understand how to create the NFA, then you understand the concept enough to move on. No one in their right mind would *actually* use a regular expression for this.

Comment: Sorry for the nitpick but the way Johannes is asking the question he is clearly trying to answer the question where 0102 is *not valid* given his sample solution.  So basically we're telling him he's asked the wrong question and instead we're answering a trivial question?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible construction:

- A regex for a string that contains at the most a single '0' digit looks like (1-9)* (0|epsilon) (1-9)* - so any number of 1-9 digits, followed by zero or 1 '0's followed by any number of 1-9 digits.
- We can now move forward by noticing that if there's only a single '1' digit it will be either to the left or to the right of the '0' digit (or the epsilon representing the missing zero digit).  So we can construct a regular expression having these two cases or'ed (|)  together.
- We can now drill further down saying that if there's only a single '2' digit it can be to the right or the left of the 1 digit in it's two possible relative locations to the '0' digit.
- So we're building a binary tree and the number of ORed regex is on the order of 2^10 which is the same order of the FSM accepting this language.  An FSM for accepting the language should have (2^10 + 1) states with each state n can be seen as it's binary representation n0n1n2n3n4n5n6n7n8n9 meaning n0 = seen digit '0', n1 = seen digit '1'. and a repeat digit transitioning to the single non-accepting state.  The initial state being zero.

If you're allowed to complement then a regex that has more than a single '0' digit would be (0-9)* 0 (0-9)* 0 (0-9)*, repeat for all digits, complement.

You can definitely be a lot more compact for Peter Taylors interpretation of no two consecutive digits that are the same.  Clearly the state for that problem is much smaller.

[SUCCINCTNESS OF THE COMPLEMENT AND INTERSECTION OF
REGULAR EXPRESSIONS](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2008/1354/pdf/22011.GeladeWouter.Paper.1354.pdf)

> "A study in [2] reveals that most of the one-unambiguous regular
>   expression used in practice take a very simple form: every alphabet
>   symbol occurs at most once. We refer to those as single-occurrence
>   regular expressions (SOREs) and show a tight exponential lower bound
>   for intersection."
>
> ...
>
> "In this section, we show that in defining the complement of a single
>   regular expression, a double-exponential size increase cannot be
>   avoided in general. In contrast, when the expression is
>   one-unambiguous its complement can be computed in polynomial time."

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to write a definition that only defines what you want, what if you tell it to generate a list of *all* strings up digits up to 10 digits in length, including duplicates, and then *subtract* the ones that contain two zeros, two ones... etc.?  Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

(I don't know which variant of regular expressions you  are referring to, if any, thus I will provide hints for the most general form of regular expressions.)

I find it a rather odd application of regular expressions since this is exactly one of the cases where they don't really provide a big benefit over other (more trivial to understand) solutions.

However, if you absolutely want to use regex, here's a hint (no solution since it's an exercise, let me know if you need more hints):

Regex allows you to recognize **[regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)**, which are generally accepted by [deterministic finite state machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_state_machine). Try to find a state machine which accepts exactly the words in the specified pattern. It'll require `2^10 = 1024` states but not `10! = 3628800`.

Comment: I don't have only 10! patterns. I have 10! alternatives in d10. If I replace d0, d1, ..., d9 in d10 by their respective right hand sides, I will have much more patterns, because each of those dX have two alternatives on their own (X|epsilon). Can you please show a string that is not matched by my naive definition?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Nevermind, I made a mistake in parsing your expression. Your solution is correct, but (as you recognized) overly verbose.

Answer (score 1):

A regular definition is a sequence of definitions on the form

d1 -> r1

d2 -> r2

...

dn -> rn

Now make the following definitions:

Zero -> 0

One -> Zero (1 Zero)* | (Zero 1)+ | 1 (Zero 1)* | (1 Zero)+

Two -> One (2 One)*   | (One 2)+  | 2 (One 2)*  | (2 One)+

Three -> Two (3 Two)* | (Two 3)+  | 3 (Two 3)*  | (3 Two)+

Four -> Three (4 Three)* | (Three 4)+ | 4 (Three 4)* | (4 Three)+

...

Nine -> Eight (9 Eight)* | (Eight 9)+ | 9 (Eight 9)* | (9 Eight)+

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "Regular Expression" in your question title. But if the regex engine supports negative lookahead, this is easily accomplished. (Here's a PHP snippet)

```php
$re = '/# Match string of digits having no repeated digits.
    ^                 # Anchor to start of string.
    (?![^0]*0[^0]*0)  # Assert 0 does not occur twice.
    (?![^1]*1[^1]*1)  # Assert 1 does not occur twice.
    (?![^2]*2[^2]*2)  # Assert 2 does not occur twice.
    (?![^3]*3[^3]*3)  # Assert 3 does not occur twice.
    (?![^4]*4[^4]*4)  # Assert 4 does not occur twice.
    (?![^5]*5[^5]*5)  # Assert 5 does not occur twice.
    (?![^6]*6[^6]*6)  # Assert 6 does not occur twice.
    (?![^7]*7[^7]*7)  # Assert 7 does not occur twice.
    (?![^8]*8[^8]*8)  # Assert 8 does not occur twice.
    (?![^9]*9[^9]*9)  # Assert 9 does not occur twice.
    [0-9]+            # Match string of only digits.
    $                 # Anchor to end of string.
    /x';
```

Comment: He's looking at the term "regular expression" in the sense of being equivalent to a "regular language". Negative lookaheads are definitely NOT a part of that definition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a neat way to write a regular expression to solve this problem without listing all the possibilities. But I find a way to reduce the complexity from O(N!) to O(2^N) by defining the DFA in the following way. In the DFA I'm going to construct, a state represent whether any digit has appeared or not.

Take strings consisting of {0, 1, 2} for example, 0 represent '0' has appeared once, 0' represent '0' hasn't appeared. All the states will look like this {012, 0'1'2', 0'12, 01'2, 012',012', 01'2, 0'12}. There will be 2^3=8 states at all. And the DFA looks like as follows:
[DFA for strings with no repeating digits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG5JO.jpg)

You can easily extend it to {0,1,2,...,9}. But there will be 1024 states at all. However, I think it's the most compact DFA with an intuitive proof. For the reason that each state has unique meaning and can't be  merged further.